# SSRS iif statement error "No accessible IIf accepts this number of arguments"

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Can someone provide some insight why I am getting this error:

"Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments"

Here is the IIf statement:

```
=iif(Sum(Fields!CallsRemaining.Value))<0,1,((Sum(Fields!TotalInventory.Value)+Sum(Fields!CallsRemaining.Value))/(Sum(Fields!TotalInventory.Value)))
```

It only has 2 arguments, so not sure why overloading.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your `=iif(Sum(Fields!CallsRemaining.Value))` IIF is ending here.

Comment: Thanks.  had to move the parenthesis.  Works now.

Answer (score 3):

Parenthesis was in the wrong place.  Fixed with simple move:

```
=iif(Sum(Fields!CallsRemaining.Value)<0,1,((Sum(Fields!TotalInventory.Value)+Sum(Fields!CallsRemaining.Value))/(Sum(Fields!TotalInventory.Value))))
```