# SSRS expression getting an error because it's expecting a ')'

Tags: reporting-services

I have opened this in notepad ++, and I don't see any missing paranthesis.  Can anybody see at a glance where a well placed paranthesis would make this script run correctly when I preview the ssrs report?

```
=IIF((InStr(Fields!GRP_NAME.Value,"SOCS") > 0 OR InStr(Fields!GRP_NAME.Value, "TOC") > 0
      , (IIF(DateAdd("YYYY",3,Fields!CP_PRD_END_DT.Value) < Fields!CP_PRD_END_DT.Value
     , "*See CO"
     IIF(Fields!SAMPLE_MONTH.Value>0
     ,"YES"
     IIF(Fields!CP_PRD_BEGIN_DT.Value < Globals!ExecutionTime
     ,"NO","FUTURE")))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
=IIF((InStr(Fields!GRP_NAME.Value,"SOCS") > 0 OR 
InStr(Fields!GRP_NAME.Value, "TOC") > 0)
  , (IIF(DateAdd("YYYY",3,Fields!CP_PRD_END_DT.Value) < 
Fields!CP_PRD_END_DT.Value
 , "*See CO"
 IIF(Fields!SAMPLE_MONTH.Value>0
 ,"YES"
 IIF(Fields!CP_PRD_BEGIN_DT.Value < Globals!ExecutionTime
 ,"NO","FUTURE"))))
```

I think you were missing an extra parenthesis at the end, if you trace your parentheses through. Also a parenthesis after your OR statement in the first line.

Also consider using a different code editor which will highlight the parentheses for you, like emacs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Now I'm getting an 'Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372309/ssrs-iif-statement-error-no-accessible-iif-accepts-this-number-of-arguments